# Pandas: hierarchical columns AND rows - use multi-index/set-index, stack/unstack, melt, or something else?

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

I have the following data in a pandas dataframe:

```
high_school_code = [110]*6 + [201]*6 + [360]*6
high_school_name = ['Jefferson High']*6 + ['Venice High']*6 + ['Beverly High']*6
subject_name = (['Math']*2 + ['Biology']*2 +['English']*2)*3
assessment_type = ['SAT', 'GPA']*9
mean_score = [560, 2.9, 620, 3.1, 600, 3.0, 680, 3.4, 590, 3.2, 710, 3.5, 640, 3.3, 570, 3.1, 730, 3.7]
standard_error = [50, 0.21, 60, 0.19, 70, 0.23, 40, 0.34, 30, 0.29, 50, 0.46, 70, 0.42, 60, 0.39, 80, 0.51]
N = [883]*6 + [1106]*6 + [978]*6
column_names = ['High_School_Code', 'High_School_Name', 'Subject_Name', 'Assessment_Type', 'Mean_Score', 'Standard_Error', 'N']

data = list(zip(high_school_code, high_school_name, subject_name, assessment_type, mean_score, standard_error, N))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)
```

[A screenshot of what the pandas dataframe looks like is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML5iF.png)

[But I need the data to be reshaped to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc5eX.png)

[It'd also be nice to reshape the data to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtGTC.png)

> I have tried using Pandas multi-index, set-index, unstack, and groupby, to no avail, and would really appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: Can you paste a sample of your data into the question? It'll be hard to help if people have to translate your images to their own dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are pretty good examples where `.set_index()` and `.unstack()` come in handy for the reshaping:

```
In [92]: (
    ...:     df
    ...:     .set_index(['High_School_Code', 'High_School_Name', 'Subject_Name', 'Assessment_Type'])
    ...:     .unstack("Assessment_Type")
    ...:     .swaplevel(axis=1)
    ...:     .sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False)
    ...: )
Out[92]:
Assessment_Type                                       GPA                             SAT
                                               Mean_Score Standard_Error     N Mean_Score Standard_Error     N
High_School_Code High_School_Name Subject_Name
110              Jefferson High   Biology             3.1           0.19   883      620.0           60.0   883
                                  English             3.0           0.23   883      600.0           70.0   883
                                  Math                2.9           0.21   883      560.0           50.0   883
201              Venice High      Biology             3.2           0.29  1106      590.0           30.0  1106
                                  English             3.5           0.46  1106      710.0           50.0  1106
                                  Math                3.4           0.34  1106      680.0           40.0  1106
360              Beverly High     Biology             3.1           0.39   978      570.0           60.0   978
                                  English             3.7           0.51   978      730.0           80.0   978
                                  Math                3.3           0.42   978      640.0           70.0   978
```

for the first one, and here's something close for the second (columns are a little out of order, but you could assign it to something and reorder after if that matters):

```
In [110]: (
     ...:     df
     ...:     .set_index(['High_School_Code', 'High_School_Name', 'Subject_Name', 'Assessment_Type'])
     ...:     .unstack(["Assessment_Type", "Subject_Name"])
     ...:     .swaplevel(0, 2, axis=1)
     ...:     .sort_index(axis=1, level=[0,1], sort_remaining=False)
     ...: )
Out[110]:
Subject_Name                         Biology                                  ...  Math
Assessment_Type                          GPA                             SAT  ...   GPA        SAT
                                  Mean_Score Standard_Error     N Mean_Score  ...     N Mean_Score Standard_Error     N
High_School_Code High_School_Name                                             ...
110              Jefferson High          3.1           0.19   883      620.0  ...   883      560.0           50.0   883
201              Venice High             3.2           0.29  1106      590.0  ...  1106      680.0           40.0  1106
360              Beverly High            3.1           0.39   978      570.0  ...   978      640.0           70.0   978
```